# Airflow BranchPythonOperator doesn't follow the specified branch

Tags: python, airflow

I have an AIRFLOW DAG with the following structure.

[image: Airflow Graph View]

All the functions that start with "check*" are BranchPythonOperator, and the function exceptionControl is a ExecuteDagRunOperator that receives every error in order to handle them.

This is the DAG configuration:

```
checkCloudFunctions = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='checkCloudFunctions',
    python_callable=check_cloud_functions,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)

checkSqlTables = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='checkSqlTables',
    python_callable=check_sql_tables,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)

checkBigQueryTable = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='checkBigQueryTable',
    python_callable=check_big_query_table,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)

labBuilt = DummyOperator(
    task_id='labBuilt',
    dag=dag)

exceptionControl = ExecuteDagRunOperator(
    task_id='exceptionControl',
    execute_dag_id="SYS_exception_control",
    python_callable=mediation.dag_trigger_exception,
    trigger_rule='one_success',
    dag=dag)

# graphs
checkCloudFunctions >> checkSqlTables
checkCloudFunctions >> exceptionControl

checkSqlTables >> checkBigQueryTable
checkSqlTables >> exceptionControl

checkBigQueryTable >> labBuilt
checkBigQueryTable >> exceptionControl
```

**The problem is** that checkSqlTables should follow to exception control but it skips and the DAG ends. The function returns "exceptionControl" as we can see in the checkSqlTables log:

```
   {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - {python_operator.py:90} INFO - Done. Returned value was: exceptionControl
   {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - {python_operator.py:118} INFO - Following branch exceptionControl
   {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - {python_operator.py:119} INFO - Marking other directly downstream tasks as skipped
   {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - {python_operator.py:128} INFO - Done.
```

I also played with the **trigger_rule** attribute (one_success, dummy...) but it doesn't seems to work.

If I delete the first step, it seems to work, so it seems it should be some kind of configuration problem with my dag.

[image]

Any ideas why the function checkSqlTables doesn't branch to exceptionControl?

EDIT: In a [new deep reading to the Airflow Documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#branching) I noticed that if a step mark a task as skipped, it will be skipped forever, so my code will never work with Branching Operators.

The solutions using branching consist on a dummy step before every step. But I have some DAG that have more than 10 steps and the schema will be completely a chaos.

Comment: The solution is simple have a "final" stage that has nothing to execute. if your code needs to end point the branch to this "final" stage.

Answer (score 0):

The issue relates how the airflow marks the status of the task.
The `exceptionControl` will be masked as skip while the `check*` task is True. As there are multiple `check*` tasks, the `check*` after the first once won't able to update the status of the `exceptionControl` as it has been masked as skip.

To solve this problem, you can create a dummy operator in each `check*` task. for example

```
         check1
           ^
        __.   _____________
       |                  |
    check2               dummy
      |                   |
     ...                exceptionControl
```

This seems to be a bug discussed in here https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/10725

Based on the above discussions, there is a fix merged here https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/11120.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30559506)